# How to remove behind the wall faucet cartridge

Tags: plumbing, faucet, cartridge

I have a leaking hot water in a bathroom faucet where main body of the faucet is behind the tile.
I tried to remove the cartridge, but cant unscrew it, it's too tight.
Also tried to spray some WD-40 around the cartridge.
I'm turning it counter clock wise using valve wrench, is it the right way to remove it or I need to do something else?

[image: cartridge]
[image: valve wrench]

Comment: I'd try a proper wrench (or at least put an extension pipe on that one). It's very difficult to apply force with such a short arm, and it _hurts_.

Comment: Yeah, put a bigger piece of pipe over that small bar. Or, use a long screwdriver with a bigger handle that you can get a more comfortable grip on. Another option would be to slip the box end of a bit (therefore long) box/combination wrench over the end of the bar you've got there. That would give you another 6-10" of leverage.

Comment: WD-40 is **W**ater **D**isplacing formula 40. Kroil, PB-Blaster, etc. are penetrating oils suited for the job you are mis-applying WD-40 for. A common error (it's similar, but really not the same.)

Comment: cut some copper pipe and used it as a lever , finally managed to turn it, thank you for the help.